# dividing the sum of two value in each group in a number format using rtf

Tags: xml, rtf, bi-publisher

I try to divide the sum of two value in each group and then I got the result. Now I want the result to in a number format '#,##0.00' but I got an error 'XML-22047: (Error) Invalid instantiation of 'xsl:when' in '_h' context.' How can I do that? Please see my code below, it's working if I remove the xdofx:format_number.

```
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'a', sum(current-group()/OR_AMOUNT))?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'b', sum(current-group()/WT_TOTAL))?>

<?xdofx:format_number(<?choose:?><?when: sum(current-group()/OR_AMOUNT)=0?>0<?end when?><?when: sum(current-group()/OR_AMOUNT)>0?><?xdofx: format_number(xdoxslt: get_variable($_XDOCTX,’b’) div xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,’a’),’#,##0.00’,’EURO’)?><?end when?><?otherwise:?>0<?end otherwise?><?end choose?>
```

Thanks,

Lawrence

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xdofx:format_number(
    <?choose:?>
        <?when: sum(current-group()/OR_AMOUNT)=0?>
            0
        <?end when?>
        <?when: sum(current-group()/OR_AMOUNT)>0?>
             <?xdofx: format_number(xdoxslt: get_variable($_XDOCTX,’b’) div xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,’a’),’#,##0.00’,’EURO’)?>
        <?end when?>
        <?otherwise:?>
            0
        <?end otherwise?>
    <?end choose?>
```

The first part `<?xdofx:format_number(` opens a bracket `(` and an element `<?`. Both are never closed. This is incorrect syntax. You also can't open an element and then open a new element before closing the first one. `<?a <?b?> ?>` is incorrect.

It is unclear why you need the first `format_number` function anyway. You are formatting the value when `OR_AMOUNT)>0` and in the other cases you have a hardcoded `0`. What are you trying to format?

This will work:

```
<?choose:?>
    <?when: sum(current-group()/OR_AMOUNT)=0?>
        0
    <?end when?>
    <?when: sum(current-group()/OR_AMOUNT)>0?>
       <?xdofx: format_number(xdoxslt: get_variable($_XDOCTX,’b’) div xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,’a’),’#,##0.00’,’EURO’)?>
    <?end when?>
    <?otherwise:?>
        0
    <?end otherwise?>
<?end choose?>
```

Or if you really want the mask on the hardcoded `0`'s:

```
<?choose:?>
    <?when: sum(current-group()/OR_AMOUNT)=0?>
        <?xdofx: format_number(0,’#,##0.00’,’EURO’)?>
    <?end when?>
    <?when: sum(current-group()/OR_AMOUNT)>0?>
        <?xdofx: format_number(xdoxslt: get_variable($_XDOCTX,’b’) div xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,’a’),’#,##0.00’,’EURO’)?>
    <?end when?>
    <?otherwise:?>
        <?xdofx: format_number(0,’#,##0.00’,’EURO’)?>
    <?end otherwise?>
<?end choose?>
```